# Is it possible to set the length of a linear gradient in CSS?

Tags: html, css

In CSS you can set the color, the position, the orientation, and the width of a linear gradient. But can you also set it's length? No, I don't want to use SVG. I'm interested in a CSS solution.

I want to make something like an eye iris with linear gradient:
[image]

But with linear gradient you get an infinite long stripe. Is it possible to limit this stripe in it's latitude?

As I said I could only set color, width, position, and orientation but not it's length:

```
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: white;
  background-image: 
  linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 70px, red 70px, black 72px, transparent 72px),
  linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 70px, red 70px, blue 72px, transparent 72px),
  radial-gradient(circle at 50px 50px, green 5px, transparent 40px);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/thadeuszlay/vy9o81dy/

Comment: No, the gradient extends the full width / height of the element it is a background of. At best you can make the gradient transparent for a portion of it's length.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't quite understand the expected output. Is it something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vy9o81dy/1/). If not can you make an image of the output you expect for the gradients in code? Maybe its just me but I couldn't make it out from the image of the eye either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add start/stop colors even in a radial gradient:https://jsfiddle.net/vy9o81dy/2/

```
radial-gradient(circle at 50px 50px, transparent 5px,  green 5px,transparent 40px);
```

---

`<edit for feed back/>` *or is this what you try to do as well ? https://jsfiddle.net/vy9o81dy/3/*

Comment: I would say that your second fiddle is what the OP wants. But I could be wrong ...